# Generating graphs based on data extent

Tags: vba, excel

I am a geologist working for a small oil company in Louisiana. I constitute our tech department, and unfortunately my experience with coding is quite limited. I have used very basic vba coding in the past, but I dont code that much in my daily job, so I have forgotten most of it. I recently discovered this site, and it has become a great resource to me. I have been able to glean bits and pieces of code from previous answers to previous questions, but I am once again stuck.

The point of my entire macro is to retrieve oil production data from a external database,  calculate certain values based on said data, and then to create graphs displaying certain aspects of the data. I have the code to accomplish the first 2 objectives, but I am struggling with the code for automating the graph making process.

My problem is that each well has a differing amount of data. For example, one well will have produced for 5 years, while the next well will have produced for 10. I need to be able to make a macro that selects all the data in the cells and then graphs that data. Presently, whenever I select columns to graph, excel will attempt to graph the entire column instead of just the extent of my data, which results in extremely large graphs with predominantly blank space. Column J needs to be the X axis, column L needs to be the Y axis. Column J has text and numbers in it and Column L just has numbers

Further, I would like the macro to  generate the name for the chart using both the worksheet name and a string of characters I will enter. The string of characters will be the same for all charts produced. I would like the charts to be line with marker charts.

An example of the naming process would go something like this

worksheet name

Percent Oil Decline

Below is the code I have generated so far:

```
Sub automated_graphs()
'
' automated_graphs Macro
'

'
    Range("L:L,J:J").Select
    Range("J1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "'EP Allen 1'!$L:$L,'EP Allen 1'!$J:$J")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='EP Allen 1'!$J:$J"
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Worksheet Name here" & Chr(13) & "Oil Production by year"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Worksheet Name here" & Chr(13) & "Oil Production by year"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 20).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 20).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoTrue
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 18
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(21, 22).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(21, 3).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoTrue
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 18
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(24, 19).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoTrue
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 18
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you and please let me know if I can provide any clarification on any points

Comment: as a side note, I know that I am not posting the code right, but I cannot figure out how to format the code to be displayed correctly on this site. I have followed the instructions but cannot seem to make it work. Any advice here would also be appreciated

Comment: In the text editor that you use to compose the question or an answer there is a button to embed code.  It's to the right of the quotes.  {}  Just paste your code into the editor, highlight it all, then click that button and you're good to go in most cases.  Sometimes you might have to end the line before it with a paragraph break [ENTER].    Take the Tour.  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
Sub DoChart()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim xVals As Range, yVals As Range
Dim co As Shape, cht As Chart, s As Series

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set co = sht.Shapes.AddChart()
    Set cht = co.Chart

    'remove any existing series
    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop 

    cht.ChartType = xlLineMarkers

    'get the extent of the XValues...
    Set xVals = sht.Range(sht.Range("J2"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
    Set yVals = xVals.Offset(0, 2)

    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    s.XValues = xVals
    s.Values = yVals

    With s.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With s.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With

    cht.HasLegend = False

    cht.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Year"

    cht.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
    cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Production"

    cht.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay)
    With cht.ChartTitle
        .Text = sht.Name & Chr(10) & "Oil Production by year"
        .Characters.Font.Size = 12
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, Thank you so much for the code. It works very well! I had a followup question. How could I automate adding data labels to the graphs? And how could I change the coding around to include more than one series on the Y axis?

Answer (score 0):

Tim's code is cracking.  I learn a lot.  Josiah, as you appear new to programming as I read Tim's code I've added some changes below that you may benefit from:

```
Set xVals = sht.Range(sht.Range("J2"), sht.Cells(SHT.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))  
' Added SHT for completeness.

Set yVals = xVals.Offset(0, 2)  
' THE ABOVE LINE WORKS BUT REPLACING WITH THE LINE BELOW MAKES IT MORE ROBUST AS 
' YOU SIMPLY CHANGE "J" to be "X" if the data moves from column J to column X.

Set yVals = intersect(xVals.entirerow, sht.columns("J"))
```